# List Of Items Appearing In Another List

Tags: vb.net, linq

I have a list of Strings. I want to do a query like the following:

SentEmails is another list that comes from the database.

```
SentEmails.Where(Function(x)x.EmailSentTo = [any of the items in my original email address list]
```

But I'm not sure how to achieve this. Bascially I want to remove any email addresses from SentEmails that aren't in my original list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Contains` extension method:

```
SentEmails.Where(Function(x) OriginalList.Contains(x.EmailSentTo))
```